# Serverless 1.0.0-beta.1.1. When I try to deploy a service using sls deploy I get following error

Tags: amazon-web-services

---

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

Error --------------------------------------------------

```
 ServerlessError: NetworkingError: The header content
 contains invalid characters

 For debugging logs, run again after setting SLS_DEBUG env var.
```

Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

Error: ServerlessError: NetworkingError: The header content contains invalid characters
    at module.exports.logError.words.forEach (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\Error.js:74:11)
    at C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless:19:15
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:504:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:561:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:606:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:681:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\chamaths\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          v1.docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

### Please report this error. We think it might be a bug.